# Chart JS tooltip appears differently when set from script instead of html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, chart.js

I am trying to customize a Chart JS element from a [template (Front Dashboard)](https://htmlstream.com/front/documentation/chartjs.html)

In the template the example is set up from the HTML as follows

```html
<canvas class="js-chart"
         data-hs-chartjs-options='{
               "type": "line",
                 "data": {
                                   "labels": ["1 May","2 May","3 May","4 May","5 May","6 May","7 May","8 May","9 May","10 May","11 May","12 May","13 May","14 May","15 May","16 May","17 May","18 May","19 May","20 May","21 May","22 May","23 May","24 May","25 May","26 May","27 May","28 May","29 May","30 May","31 May"],
                                   "datasets": [{
                                    "data": [25,18,30,31,35,35,60,60,60,75,21,20,24,20,18,17,15,17,30,120,120,120,100,90,75,90,90,90,75,70,60],
                                    "backgroundColor": ["rgba(55, 125, 255, 0)", "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)"],
                                    "borderColor": "#377dff",
                                    "borderWidth": 2,
                                    "pointRadius": 0,
                                    "pointHoverRadius": 0
                                  }]
                                },
                                "options": {
                                   "scales": {
                                     "yAxes": [{
                                       "display": false
                                     }],
                                     "xAxes": [{
                                       "display": false
                                     }]
                                   },
                                  "hover": {
                                    "mode": "nearest",
                                    "intersect": false
                                  },
                                  "tooltips": {
                                    "postfix": "%",
                                    "hasIndicator": true,
                                    "intersect": false
                                  }
                                }
                              }'>
                                </canvas>
```

This displays a nicely formatted Tooltip

[image]

but when I setup the chart from script with the same structure/config, the tooltip formatting changes and it also is clipped inside the bounds of the chart.

[image]

```js
var myData = [];
var myLabels = [];
var myOccupancy;

function showChart() {
  myData = myOccupancy.DataList;
  myLabels = myOccupancy.LabelList;
  console.log(myData);
  console.log(myLabels);
  let popCanvasName = document.getElementById("occChart");
  let barChartName = new Chart(popCanvasName, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: myLabels,
      datasets: [
        {
          data: myData,
          backgroundColor: ['rgba(55, 125, 255, 0)', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'],
          borderColor: '#377dff',
          borderWidth: 2,
          pointRadius: 0,
          pointHoverRadius: 0
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [
          {
            display: false
          }
        ],
        xAxes: [
          {
            display: false
          }
        ]
      },
      hover: {
        mode: 'nearest',
        intersect: false
      },
      tooltips: {
        postfix: '%',
        hasIndicator: false,
        intersect: false
      },
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  });
}

function getChartData() {
  return fetch('./Index?handler=OccupancyChartData', {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    }
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.text();
    } else {
      throw Error('Response Not OK');
    }
})
.then(function(text) {
    try {
return JSON.parse(text);
    } catch (err) {
throw Error('Method Not Found');
    }
})
.then(function(responseJSON) {
    myOccupancy = responseJSON;
    showChart();
});
};


$(document).on('ready', function() {

  getChartData();

  // initialization of circles
  $('.js-circle').each(function() {
    var circle = $.HSCore.components.HSCircles.init($(this));
  });

  $('.js-chart').each(function () {
    var chart = $.HSCore.components.HSChartJS.init($(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4"></script>
<!-- as you are using v2.x of chart.js -->

<canvas id="occChart" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason the formatting is different is because `chart.js` does not support the options `postfix` and `hasIndicator`, seems like your wrapper is styling the tooltip and taking those extra options and transforms the tooltip itself. If you want to make your chart via script you need to follow the [normal documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/).

About the tooltip getting cut off guess its somewhere else that it might go wrong because standard behaviour it adjusts the tooltip placement so that it is in the chart area:

```js
const options = {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
     labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
     datasets: [
       {
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 2, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
       },   
       {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
       }
     ]
   },
   options: {
   }
};

const ctx =  document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');

new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```css
canvas { 
   background-color : #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4"></script>

<canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code in your question is for ..... `chart.js` **v2.xx**

**v3.xx** is not backwards compatible with **v2.xx**
**v3.xx** has better performance, hence you might consider migrating

Anyhow, I offer you 2 solutions for both versions:

1. code for `chart.js` v2.9.4  (latest for **v2.x**)
2. code for `chart.js` v3.5.1  (latest for **v3.x**)
   I migrated your code to v3.x

I used some sample data (as I cannot fetch your data from here).

### **v2.x**

Replacing `postfix: '%'` with following callback function:

```js
options: {
  ...
      tooltips: {
        usePointStyle: true,
        // postfix: '%',
        callbacks: {  // <-- to replace 'postfix:'
          label: function(context) {
            return context.yLabel + '%' || '';
          }
        }
  ...
}
```

See following complete code for **v2.x** and **Run code snippet** to see result:

```js
const popCanvasName = document.getElementById('occChart').getContext('2d');

let myData = [];
let myLabels = [];
const myOccupancy = { // <-- let's use sample data meanwhile
  "LabelList" : ["2021-08-02","2021-08-03","2021-08-04","2021-08-05","2021-08-06"],
  "DataList" : [39,41,42,30,21]
};

function showChart() {
  myData = myOccupancy.DataList;
  myLabels = myOccupancy.LabelList;
  // console.log(myData);
  // console.log(myLabels);

  const barChartName = new Chart(popCanvasName, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: myLabels,
      datasets: [{
        data: myData,
        backgroundColor: ['rgba(55, 125, 255, 0.5)', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'],
        fill: true, // <-- to show backgroundColor
        borderColor: '#377dff',
        borderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 0,
        pointHoverRadius: 0
      }]
    },
    options: {
      aspectRatio: 5,
      responsive: true,
      interaction: {
        intersect: false,
        mode: 'nearest'
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          display: false
        }],
        xAxes: [{
          type: 'time', // load moment.js and adapter for this to work
          display: true,
          time: {
            unit: 'week',
            displayFormats: {
              hour: 'h:mm a',
              day: 'ddd',
              week: 'dddd',
              month: 'MMM'
            },
            tooltipFormat: 'dddd, MMM DD, YYYY' // modify format string to your needs
          }
        }]
      },
      tooltips: {
        usePointStyle: true,
        // postfix: '%',
        callbacks: {  // you can use this callback
          label: function(context) {
            return context.yLabel + '%' || '';
          }
        },
        // hasIndicator: true,
        intersect: false
      },
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  });
};

function getChartData() {
  return fetch('./Index?handler=OccupancyChartData', {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    }
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.text();
    } else {
      throw Error('Response Not OK');
    }
})
.then(function(text) {
    try {
return JSON.parse(text);
    } catch (err) {
throw Error('Method Not Found');
    }
})
.then(function(responseJSON) {
    myOccupancy = responseJSON;
    showChart();
});
};

showChart();

/* We use sample data meanwhile
$(document).on('ready', function() {

  // getChartData();  <-- we use sample data meanwhile

  // initialization of circles


  $('.js-circle').each(function() {
    var circle = $.HSCore.components.HSCircles.init($(this));
  });

  $('.js-chart').each(function () {
    var chart = $.HSCore.components.HSChartJS.init($(this));
  });

});
*/
```

```html
<!-- get latest version of Chart.js v2.x -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4"></script>

<!-- You need moment.js and adapter for time to work at x-Axis -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment"></script>

<canvas id="occChart" width="320"></canvas>
```

### **v3.x**

Replacing `postfix: '%'` with following callback function:

```js
options: {
  ...
    plugins: { // toolip within plugin now
      tooltip: { // before tooltips  --> now toolip (singular)
        usePointStyle: true,
        // postfix: '%',
        callbacks: {  // <-- replacing 'postfix:'
            label: function(context) {
              return context.parsed.y + '%' || '';
            }
        }
    }
  ...
}
```

See following complete code for **v3.x** and **Run code snippet** to see result:

```js
const popCanvasName = document.getElementById('occChart').getContext('2d');

let myData = [];
let myLabels = [];
const myOccupancy = { // <-- let's use sample data meanwhile
  "LabelList" : ["2021-08-02","2021-08-03","2021-08-04","2021-08-05","2021-08-06"],
  "DataList" : [39,41,42,30,21]
};

function showChart() {
  myData = myOccupancy.DataList;
  myLabels = myOccupancy.LabelList;
  // console.log(myData);
  // console.log(myLabels);

  const barChartName = new Chart(popCanvasName, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: myLabels,
      datasets: [{
        data: myData,
        backgroundColor: ['rgba(55, 125, 255, 0.5)', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'],
        fill: true, // <-- to show backgroundColor
        borderColor: '#377dff',
        borderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 0,
        pointHoverRadius: 0
      }]
    },
    options: {
      aspectRatio: 5,
      responsive: true,
      interaction: { // before hover  --> now 'interaction'
        intersect: false,
        mode: 'nearest'
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: { // before '[{'   now '{' (not an array anymore)
          display: false
        },
        xAxes: { // before '[{'  --> now '{' (not an array anymore)
          type: 'time', // load moment.js and adapter for this to work
          display: false,
          time: {
            unit: 'week',
            displayFormats: {
              hour: 'h:mm a',
              day: 'ddd',
              week: 'dddd',
              month: 'MMM'
            },
            tooltipFormat: 'dddd, MMM DD, YYYY' // modify format string to your needs
          }
        }
      },
      plugins: {
        tooltip: { // before tooltips  --> now toolip (singular) within plugin
          usePointStyle: true,
          // postfix: '%',
          callbacks: {  // <-- replacing 'postfix:'
            label: function(context) {
              return context.parsed.y + '%' || '';
            }
          },
          hasIndicator: true,
          intersect: false
        },
        legend: { // --> now within plugin
          display: false
        }
      }
    }
  });
};

function getChartData() {
  return fetch('./Index?handler=OccupancyChartData', {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    }
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.text();
    } else {
      throw Error('Response Not OK');
    }
})
.then(function(text) {
    try {
return JSON.parse(text);
    } catch (err) {
throw Error('Method Not Found');
    }
})
.then(function(responseJSON) {
    myOccupancy = responseJSON;
    showChart();
});
};

showChart();

/* We use sample data meanwhile
$(document).on('ready', function() {

  // getChartData();  <-- we use sample data meanwhile

  // initialization of circles


  $('.js-circle').each(function() {
    var circle = $.HSCore.components.HSCircles.init($(this));
  });

  $('.js-chart').each(function () {
    var chart = $.HSCore.components.HSChartJS.init($(this));
  });

});
*/
```

```html
<!-- get latest version of Chart.js, now at v3.5.1 -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<!-- You need moment.js and adapter for time to work at x-Axis -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment"></script>

<canvas id="occChart" width="320"></canvas>
```

Comment: Does not seem to be the issue since the documentation is written for V2 highly unlikely it's using V3

Comment: @LeeLenalee Looking at documentation of the [template (Front Dashboard)](https://htmlstream.com/front/documentation/chartjs.html) the libraries have to be loaded manually anyhow. At least I provided a constructive contribution instead of just a comment. You may post same code vor V2 - stackoverflow is all about **answers** and **solutions**.

Comment: Well stack is also the last place you go to, its clear he didnt read the documentation or took verry low effort in doing so so low effort input = low effort output. So instead of contributing an answer that doesnt help since its not the version he contribute a good one, or if he is using v3 it proves my point he didnt read any documentation

Comment: Sure bro, if it makes you sleep wel, be happy

Comment: Also if you really want to do it good make sure the tooltip color matches because in his image as it should be the text is slightly grey and not white

Comment: @LeeLenalee and you should use **Run code snippet** in-house, instead of external link to **jsfiddle**

Comment: Could, like I said too much effort but seems like remembering things ain't your strong point